# Better way to fix "Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 5.21:26" in LUIS

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have created a LUIS bot application which is not working since last 4 days.I am getting the below error

"sorry my bot code is having an issue."

I trouble shoot the LUIS end point URL in browser i got the below response

{ "statusCode": 403, "message": "Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 5.21:26:15." }.

I am not sure why am i getting this error and do we have any other way to get this working instead of waiting?

Comment: I guess you are using a Free tier API key for LUIS?

Comment: Yes,  After changing the tier it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have reached the limit on the authoring key.You can increase your endpoint limits by increasing from Free to Standard. Go to the cognitive services blade [here](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/Resources/resourceType/Microsoft.CognitiveServices%2Faccounts). Then go to your Cognitive Services application. Then select Pricing Tier. Increase from Free to Standard. Please see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#key-limits) for more info.

If you have not configured a Cognitive Service, you can do that by going into Manage->Keys and Endpoints->Assign resource within your LUIS application.